# How to make a scroll bar when overflow in HTML and css

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble dealing with the scroll bar in CSS
When I try to add and scroll bar when the song list container overflow, it will just keep expanding instead of making a bar , i am really confused
here is my code

```
.song-list-container{
    overflow-y: scroll;
}



        <div class="playlist">
            <h2>Playlist</h2>
            <ul class="song-list-container">
                <li data-src="songs/SWEET - I THOUGHT YOU WANTED TO DANCE - Tyler the creator" data-name="SWEET - I THOUGHT YOU WANTED TO DANCE" data-index="0"><span>SWEET - I THOUGHT YOU WANTED TO DANCE </span><span>09:48</span></li>
                <li data-src="songs/Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-name="Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-index="0"><span>Cigarettes - Juice wrld  </span><span> 03:47</span></li>
                <li data-src="songs/Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-name="Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-index="0"><span>Cigarettes - Juice wrld  </span><span> 03:47</span></li>
                <li data-src="songs/Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-name="Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-index="0"><span>Cigarettes - Juice wrld  </span><span> 03:47</span></li>
                <li data-src="songs/Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-name="Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-index="0"><span>Cigarettes - Juice wrld  </span><span> 03:47</span></li>
                <li data-src="songs/Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-name="Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-index="0"><span>Cigarettes - Juice wrld  </span><span> 03:47</span></li>
                <li data-src="songs/Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-name="Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-index="0"><span>Cigarettes - Juice wrld  </span><span> 03:47</span></li>
                <li data-src="songs/Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-name="Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-index="0"><span>Cigarettes - Juice wrld  </span><span> 03:47</span></li>
                <li data-src="songs/Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-name="Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-index="0"><span>Cigarettes - Juice wrld  </span><span> 03:47</span></li>
                <li data-src="songs/Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-name="Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-index="0"><span>Cigarettes - Juice wrld  </span><span> 03:47</span></li>
                <li data-src="songs/Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-name="Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-index="0"><span>Cigarettes - Juice wrld  </span><span> 03:47</span></li>
                <li data-src="songs/Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-name="Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-index="0"><span>Cigarettes - Juice wrld  </span><span> 03:47</span></li>
                <li data-src="songs/Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-name="Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-index="0"><span>Cigarettes - Juice wrld  </span><span> 03:47</span></li>
                <li data-src="songs/Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-name="Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-index="0"><span>Cigarettes - Juice wrld  </span><span> 03:47</span></li>
                <li data-src="songs/Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-name="Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-index="0"><span>Cigarettes - Juice wrld  </span><span> 03:47</span></li>
                <li data-src="songs/Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-name="Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-index="0"><span>Cigarettes - Juice wrld  </span><span> 03:47</span></li>
                <li data-src="songs/Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-name="Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-index="0"><span>Cigarettes - Juice wrld  </span><span> 03:47</span></li>
                <li data-src="songs/Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-name="Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-index="0"><span>Cigarettes - Juice wrld  </span><span> 03:47</span></li>
                <li data-src="songs/Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-name="Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-index="0"><span>Cigarettes - Juice wrld  </span><span> 03:47</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please clean up your code first. You have li elements inside divs. This is not legal HTML see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li you also have a typo dev (?)

Comment: @AHaworth I have cleaned it up, still doesn't seem to work

Comment: You put your screenshot into the code snippet that makes it invisible. Please modify your format properly again.

Comment: Stuff will keep being added to the end of an element and the element will just keep expanding to accommodate it unless you tell it what maximum height it can expand to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `max-height` (any value that fits your need) to the container element and change the `overflow-y:` setting to `auto`. That way the scroll bar will only appear if the list is *longer*  than the defined `max-height`:

```css
.song-list-container {
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="playlist">
  <h2>Playlist</h2>
  <ul class="song-list-container">
    <li data-src="songs/SWEET - I THOUGHT YOU WANTED TO DANCE - Tyler the creator" data-name="SWEET - I THOUGHT YOU WANTED TO DANCE" data-index="0"><span>SWEET - I THOUGHT YOU WANTED TO DANCE </span><span>09:48</span></li>
    <li data-src="songs/Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-name="Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-index="0"><span>Cigarettes - Juice wrld  </span><span> 03:47</span></li>
    <li data-src="songs/Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-name="Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-index="0"><span>Cigarettes - Juice wrld  </span><span> 03:47</span></li>
    <li data-src="songs/Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-name="Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-index="0"><span>Cigarettes - Juice wrld  </span><span> 03:47</span></li>
    <li data-src="songs/Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-name="Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-index="0"><span>Cigarettes - Juice wrld  </span><span> 03:47</span></li>
    <li data-src="songs/Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-name="Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-index="0"><span>Cigarettes - Juice wrld  </span><span> 03:47</span></li>
    <li data-src="songs/Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-name="Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-index="0"><span>Cigarettes - Juice wrld  </span><span> 03:47</span></li>
    <li data-src="songs/Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-name="Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-index="0"><span>Cigarettes - Juice wrld  </span><span> 03:47</span></li>
    <li data-src="songs/Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-name="Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-index="0"><span>Cigarettes - Juice wrld  </span><span> 03:47</span></li>
    <li data-src="songs/Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-name="Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-index="0"><span>Cigarettes - Juice wrld  </span><span> 03:47</span></li>
    <li data-src="songs/Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-name="Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-index="0"><span>Cigarettes - Juice wrld  </span><span> 03:47</span></li>
    <li data-src="songs/Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-name="Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-index="0"><span>Cigarettes - Juice wrld  </span><span> 03:47</span></li>
    <li data-src="songs/Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-name="Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-index="0"><span>Cigarettes - Juice wrld  </span><span> 03:47</span></li>
    <li data-src="songs/Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-name="Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-index="0"><span>Cigarettes - Juice wrld  </span><span> 03:47</span></li>
    <li data-src="songs/Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-name="Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-index="0"><span>Cigarettes - Juice wrld  </span><span> 03:47</span></li>
    <li data-src="songs/Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-name="Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-index="0"><span>Cigarettes - Juice wrld  </span><span> 03:47</span></li>
    <li data-src="songs/Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-name="Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-index="0"><span>Cigarettes - Juice wrld  </span><span> 03:47</span></li>
    <li data-src="songs/Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-name="Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-index="0"><span>Cigarettes - Juice wrld  </span><span> 03:47</span></li>
    <li data-src="songs/Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-name="Cigarettes - Juice wrld" data-index="0"><span>Cigarettes - Juice wrld  </span><span> 03:47</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Specify a `max-height` after which the scroll need to implemented

like

```
.song-list-container{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    max-height: 250px;
}
```

Comment: Add max-height attribute to .song-list-container class

Comment: I have tried it ,didnt work

Answer (score -1):

Maybe [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/38tra1kx/1/) can help you forward. I've created an example where I used your code and forced the `overflow-y` on the `.playlist`. I've added some additional styling to make it clear where I was looking add.

```css
.playlist {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  max-width: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.song-list-container{
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.